# Unable to install libevent without admin priviledges

Tags: compiling, tmux, make

I just downloaded libevent-2.0.21-stable, which I am hoping to compile so that I can use `tmux`. However, when I run:

```
./configure --prefix=/path/to/libevent-2.0.21-stable/
make
make install
```

everything seems to work well until the last few lines, where I get the following error:

```
...
make[3]: Leaving directory `/nfs/titan7/u11/vid/bin/utils/libevent-2.0.21-stable'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/nfs/titan7/u11/vid/bin/utils/libevent-2.0.21-stable'
Making install in include
make[2]: Entering directory `/nfs/titan7/u11/vid/bin/utils/libevent-2.0.21-stable/include'
make[3]: Entering directory `/nfs/titan7/u11/vid/bin/utils/libevent-2.0.21-stable/include'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
 /bin/mkdir -p '/d4m/vid/bin/utils/libevent-2.0.21-stable/include'
 /bin/mkdir -p '/d4m/vid/bin/utils/libevent-2.0.21-stable/include/event2'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644  event2/buffer.h event2/buffer_compat.h event2/bufferevent.h event2/bufferevent_compat.h event2/bufferevent_ssl.h event2/buffereve
nt_struct.h event2/dns.h event2/dns_compat.h event2/dns_struct.h event2/event.h event2/event_compat.h event2/event_struct.h event2/http.h event2/http_compat.h
 event2/http_struct.h event2/keyvalq_struct.h event2/listener.h event2/rpc.h event2/rpc_compat.h event2/rpc_struct.h event2/tag.h event2/tag_compat.h event2/t
hread.h event2/util.h '/d4m/vid/bin/utils/libevent-2.0.21-stable/include/event2'                                                                             
/usr/bin/install: `event2/buffer.h' and `/d4m/vid/bin/utils/libevent-2.0.21-stable/include/event2/buffer.h' are the same file
/usr/bin/install: `event2/buffer_compat.h' and `/d4m/vid/bin/utils/libevent-2.0.21-stable/include/event2/buffer_compat.h' are the same file
/usr/bin/install: `event2/bufferevent.h' and `/d4m/vid/bin/utils/libevent-2.0.21-stable/include/event2/bufferevent.h' are the same file
/usr/bin/install: `event2/bufferevent_compat.h' and `/d4m/vid/bin/utils/libevent-2.0.21-stable/include/event2/bufferevent_compat.h' are the same file
/usr/bin/install: `event2/bufferevent_ssl.h' and `/d4m/vid/bin/utils/libevent-2.0.21-stable/include/event2/bufferevent_ssl.h' are the same file
/usr/bin/install: `event2/bufferevent_struct.h' and `/d4m/vid/bin/utils/libevent-2.0.21-stable/include/event2/bufferevent_struct.h' are the same file
/usr/bin/install: `event2/dns.h' and `/d4m/vid/bin/utils/libevent-2.0.21-stable/include/event2/dns.h' are the same file
/usr/bin/install: `event2/dns_compat.h' and `/d4m/vid/bin/utils/libevent-2.0.21-stable/include/event2/dns_compat.h' are the same file
/usr/bin/install: `event2/dns_struct.h' and `/d4m/vid/bin/utils/libevent-2.0.21-stable/include/event2/dns_struct.h' are the same file
/usr/bin/install: `event2/event.h' and `/d4m/vid/bin/utils/libevent-2.0.21-stable/include/event2/event.h' are the same file
/usr/bin/install: `event2/event_compat.h' and `/d4m/vid/bin/utils/libevent-2.0.21-stable/include/event2/event_compat.h' are the same file
/usr/bin/install: `event2/event_struct.h' and `/d4m/vid/bin/utils/libevent-2.0.21-stable/include/event2/event_struct.h' are the same file
/usr/bin/install: `event2/http.h' and `/d4m/vid/bin/utils/libevent-2.0.21-stable/include/event2/http.h' are the same file
/usr/bin/install: `event2/http_compat.h' and `/d4m/vid/bin/utils/libevent-2.0.21-stable/include/event2/http_compat.h' are the same file
/usr/bin/install: `event2/http_struct.h' and `/d4m/vid/bin/utils/libevent-2.0.21-stable/include/event2/http_struct.h' are the same file
/usr/bin/install: `event2/keyvalq_struct.h' and `/d4m/vid/bin/utils/libevent-2.0.21-stable/include/event2/keyvalq_struct.h' are the same file
/usr/bin/install: `event2/listener.h' and `/d4m/vid/bin/utils/libevent-2.0.21-stable/include/event2/listener.h' are the same file
/usr/bin/install: `event2/rpc.h' and `/d4m/vid/bin/utils/libevent-2.0.21-stable/include/event2/rpc.h' are the same file
/usr/bin/install: `event2/rpc_compat.h' and `/d4m/vid/bin/utils/libevent-2.0.21-stable/include/event2/rpc_compat.h' are the same file
/usr/bin/install: `event2/rpc_struct.h' and `/d4m/vid/bin/utils/libevent-2.0.21-stable/include/event2/rpc_struct.h' are the same file
/usr/bin/install: `event2/tag.h' and `/d4m/vid/bin/utils/libevent-2.0.21-stable/include/event2/tag.h' are the same file
/usr/bin/install: `event2/tag_compat.h' and `/d4m/vid/bin/utils/libevent-2.0.21-stable/include/event2/tag_compat.h' are the same file
/usr/bin/install: `event2/thread.h' and `/d4m/vid/bin/utils/libevent-2.0.21-stable/include/event2/thread.h' are the same file
/usr/bin/install: `event2/util.h' and `/d4m/vid/bin/utils/libevent-2.0.21-stable/include/event2/util.h' are the same file
make[3]: *** [install-nobase_includeHEADERS] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/nfs/titan7/u11/vid/bin/utils/libevent-2.0.21-stable/include'
make[2]: *** [install-am] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/nfs/titan7/u11/vid/bin/utils/libevent-2.0.21-stable/include'
make[1]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/nfs/titan7/u11/vid/bin/utils/libevent-2.0.21-stable'
make: *** [install] Error 2
make install  6.15s user 8.22s system 86% cpu 16.622 total
```

Running `make verify` also returns the following error:

```
EPOLL
 test-eof: OKAY
 test-weof: OKAY
 test-time: OKAY
 test-changelist: OKAY
 regress: OKAY
EPOLL (changelist)
 test-eof: OKAY
 test-weof: OKAY
 test-time: OKAY
 test-changelist: OKAY
 regress: 
  FAIL regress.c:717: assert(abs(timeval_msec_diff(((&start)), ((&res.tvs[2]))) - (500)) <= 50): 145 vs 50main/persistent_active_timeout: 
  [persistent_active_timeout FAILED]
1/179 TESTS FAILED. (0 skipped)
FAILED
DEVPOLL
Skipping test
POLL
 test-eof: OKAY
 test-weof: OKAY
 test-time: OKAY
 test-changelist: OKAY
 regress: OKAY
SELECT
 test-eof: OKAY
 test-weof: OKAY
 test-time: OKAY
 test-changelist: OKAY
 regress: OKAY
WIN32
Skipping test
FAIL: ../test/test.sh
==================
1 of 1 test failed
==================
make[4]: *** [check-TESTS] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory `/nfs/titan7/u11/vid/bin/utils/libevent-2.0.21-stable/test'
make[3]: *** [check-am] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory `/nfs/titan7/u11/vid/bin/utils/libevent-2.0.21-stable/test'
make[2]: *** [check] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/nfs/titan7/u11/vid/bin/utils/libevent-2.0.21-stable/test'
make[1]: *** [check-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/nfs/titan7/u11/vid/bin/utils/libevent-2.0.21-stable'
make: *** [check] Error 2
make verify  22.71s user 24.82s system 16% cpu 4:41.78 total
```

I am stuck at this point. Why do the compilation and verification fail?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you want to install the files to the same place where you extracted the tarball.  Extract the tarball to a different place or try a different prefix and it should work (worse option: use `make install -i` to ignore all error messages).

Comment: Interesting. That fixed the problem. Thanks! I presume that it's advisable to always install to a different folder on which one uncompresses a tarball?

Comment: What I'd do is to `./configure --prefix=$HOME` to install in your home directory, and use from there.

Comment: @user27915816 Yes, I recommend to install always to a different folder. Using [xstow](http://xstow.sourceforge.net/) you can have a private install directory for every software, and then have automatically created symlinks to a generic folder such that you do not need to adapt your PATH/LD_LIBRARY_PATH settings everytime, but can easily uninstall software packages. See [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/39891/15241) and [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/16397/15241) for more details.