# Package management without the need of root permission

Tags: apt, package-management, non-root-user

Am looking for a way to install packages in home folder. This [thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/339/how-can-i-install-a-package-without-root-access) suggests using

```
apt-get source 
./configure --prefix=$HOME
```

However, it doesn't provide a way to manage dependencies like apt-get install does. Tools like Homebrew have a limited number of packages. Is there a way to use apt-get, but to install in home folder.

Comment: Related: [Non-Root Package Managers](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5535/non-root-package-managers)

Comment: Another one: [Install package without root access](http://askubuntu.com/questions/339/how-can-i-install-a-package-without-root-access)

Comment: You could certainly build deb packages that install in your home directory. As far as I know, there is no reason you cannot do that. However, this is not in general a good idea and is a violation of the FHS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE:** [Linuxbrew](https://github.com/Linuxbrew/brew) has been merged into Homebrew

> Linuxbrew/brew has been merged into Homebrew/brew! Existing installations of Linuxbrew will be automatically migrated to Homebrew. Linuxbrew/brew will no longer be updated. See the Homebrew documentation of [Linuxbrew](https://github.com/Linuxbrew/brew) and the Homebrew 2.0.0 blog post.
>
> > Homebrew officially supports Linux and Windows 10 with Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL). “Homebrew on Linux” is called “Linuxbrew”. You can install it in your home directory, so it does not require sudo, and use it to install software that your host distribution’s package manager does not provide. Linuxbrew uses its own repository for formulae: Linuxbrew/homebrew-core.

**NOTE:** Original answer is below for historical purposes.

---

I'd take a look at [Linuxbrew](https://github.com/Homebrew/linuxbrew).

> A fork of Homebrew for Linux
>
> #### Features
>
> - Can install software to a home directory and so does not require sudo
> - Install software not packaged by the native distribution
> - Install up-to-date versions of software when the native distribution is old
> - Use the same package manager to manage both your Mac and Linux machines

The formulas list looks pretty extensive to me.

- https://github.com/Linuxbrew/brew/tree/master/Library/Homebrew

As of 2014-06-03 there are ~2832 Formulas on that page.

#### References

- [Is there any way to get APT to install packages to my home directory?](https://serverfault.com/questions/23734/is-there-any-way-to-get-apt-to-install-packages-to-my-home-directory)

Comment: Thanks! I was little concerned over the available libraries in Linuxbrew, but the list seems comprehensive.

Comment: @alpha_cod - yes I'd never heard of this package until your Q and was pleasantly surprised with how extensive a list they had compiled.

Comment: the link you posted doesn't work anymore, it 404s

Comment: @Rainb - ty for the heads up, updated A'er to reflect changes.