# Why don't most common Linux package managers allow package installation for normal users?

Tags: linux, yum, dpkg, non-root-user

I tend to install quite a lot of packages with `./configure --prefix=$HOME && make && make install`. Why can't I do this as easily with dpkg or yum? Or if I somehow can, what is the way to do that?

Comment: Are you asking why non-root users are not permitted to install packages using dpkg/yum ?

Comment: Yes and/or why was it decided not to include such functionality.

Comment: Well, it would be like giving the lunatics the keys to the asylum.....if anyone could install any package, they could easily bypass the security lovingly applied by the systems administrators.

Comment: @steve: You're missing the point. I'm asking about installing the packages in my home directory.

Comment: Do you just want a package manager to allow relocatable install ?  That's there, for example see http://rpm.org/api/4.4.2.2/relocatable.html

Comment: @steve: That's closer to what I want, but I wish there was something like this for `yum` or `apt-get` rather than `rpm` or `dpkg`. Having dependencies install themselves is nice.

Comment: It might be that I committed a duplicate: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/5535/26489

Answer (score 2):

Some package managers support relocation.  RPM in particular supports relocation, where the package itself has been built to support it.  More information on `rpm --relocate` at [rpm.org:Relocatable packages](http://rpm.org/api/4.4.2.2/relocatable.html)

A comment by the maintainer of `yum` in 2008 (Seth Vidal) suggests that support for relocation within yum is unlikely.
[yum mailing list:Yum relocate option](http://lists.baseurl.org/pipermail/yum/2008-February/021674.html)