# Installing Nix or Guix without root permissions?

Tags: non-root-user, nix, guix

[This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/8665/4531) to the question [Non-Root Package Managers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5535/non-root-package-managers) suggests  [**Nix**](http://nixos.org/nix/) as a solution. However, [the installation documentation says](http://nixos.org/nix/manual/#chap-installation):

> The script will invoke `sudo` to create `/nix` if it doesn’t already
>   exist. If you don’t have sudo, you should manually create `/nix` first
>   as `root`.

I don't have permissions to do either on a target machine. Does that mean that there is no way for me to install and therefore use Nix unless sysadmin agrees to install it?

Does the same apply to [Guix](http://www.gnu.org/software/guix/)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try it installing nix using [PRoot](https://nixos.wiki/wiki/Nix_Installation_Guide). Or you can build for your custom prefix:

```
NIX_STORE_DIR=/opt/custom/store \
NIX_STATE_DIR=/opt/custom/var/nix \
NIX_DB_DIR=/opt/custom/var/nix/db \
    nix-build ...
```

Comment: The link is not available anymore.

Comment: You can use archive.org in the meantime: https://web.archive.org/web/20160829175309/https://nixos.org/wiki/How_to_install_nix_in_home_(on_another_distribution)#PRoot_Installation

Answer (score 3):

Both Nix and Guix, when building from source, allow you to pass the `--with-store-dir=${alternative_store_dir}` option to their configure scripts. This defaults to `/nix/store` and `/gnu/store` respectively. You can set this to somewhere you have write access to.

Be aware though that, for both, changing the store path means changing the hash of a lot of derivatives. This means that you mostly cannot use pre-built binary packages any more and will end up building (almost) everything from source.

Comment: Giel (& @clacke, who commented above) could you clarify this? I see [this link](https://hpc.guix.info/blog/2017/09/reproducibility-and-root-privileges/) explaining why guix needs root: it needs chroot & setuid. So compiling with a different store, doesn't seem to change the need for root. The only way I can see to use it (almost) without root, is described in the intro [here](https://github.com/pjotrp/guix-notes/blob/master/GUIX-NO-ROOT.org). If you can put files in /guix/store, then you can compile on a machine that has guix & copy over. If I'm missing something, I'd appreciate a full answer.

Comment: The only way I can see this working without /guix/store being writable, is if you install guix from source using the --with-store-dir flag on a computer where you do have root.  You would have to use a directory /home/uname/guix, where uname is the same as that on the machine where you don't have root. Then install the packages that interest you, and finally copy them over to /home/uname/guix on the computer where you don't have root.  As with @clacke's comment, this would mean recompiling the universe from scratch.

Comment: I think it should be possible to get rid of the chroot usage by using filesystem namespaces (`unshare`) which shouldn't require root permissions. I'm not sure if that is the only remaining thing requiring root though...

Answer (score 0):

`nix-user-chroot` worked for me
https://nixos.wiki/wiki/Nix_Installation_Guide#nix-user-chroot
https://github.com/nix-community/nix-user-chroot
ps. nix commands work if shell started as login (`nix-user-chroot ~/.nix bash -l`); I also needed to run install script one more time from nix user to finally make it work.

Answer (score -1):

You can indeed install Guix without the final `make install`, thus with no need of root privileges: http://dustycloud.org/blog/guix-package-manager-without-make-install/

Comment: You still need root to create `/gnu/store`.

Comment: IIRC, we can set up environment variables to put the store somewhere we don't need to be root.

Comment: You can also recompile guix to use another store path by default, but the point is that you then have to recompile the universe from scratch, and the last time I tried back in 2014 or so it didn't even work, because some parts were making assumptions about the store path. `nix run` now has support for an alternate store path, but what it does is use filesystem namespaces (`unshare`) to mount the alternate store path at `/nix/store`. The equivalent could be done for guix as well, but AFAIK nobody has done it yet.

Comment: The daemon has to run as root.  If you look at that link, you will see a lot of sudo's.