# How to install Nix "silently" without having to answer to prompts? (e.g., to install it from a shell script)

Tags: nix

I have a script that needs to be run on brand new virtual machines, but it depends on Nix being present, and I don't want to manually install it every time.

Comment: [Thread on the NixOS Discourse.](https://discourse.nixos.org/t/how-to-run-the-nix-installer-silently-from-a-shell-script/25633)

Answer (score 2):

1. Use the [nixos.org](https://nixos.org/download.html) installer with the `--yes` option.

   Examples:

   - [nix.dev](https://nix.dev/tutorials/install-nix) version:

     ```
     curl -L https://nixos.org/nix/install | sh -s -- --daemon --yes
     ```
   - [nixos.org](https://nixos.org/download.html) version

     ```
     sh <(curl -L https://nixos.org/nix/install) --daemon --yes
     ```
2. Use the [DeterminateSystems installer](https://github.com/DeterminateSystems/nix-installer) with the [--no-confirm option](https://determinate.systems/posts/determinate-nix-installer#a-flexible-installer).

   > NOTE
   > Not sure how to use this option with
   >
   > ```
   >  curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf -L https://install.determinate.systems/nix | sh -s -- install
   > ```
   >
   > but hoping to test it soon.

This script seemed to do the trick for me:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

curl -L https://nixos.org/nix/install | sh -s -- --daemon --yes

if [ -e '/nix/var/nix/profiles/default/etc/profile.d/nix-daemon.sh' ]; then
  . '/nix/var/nix/profiles/default/etc/profile.d/nix-daemon.sh'
fi

# Testing whether Nix is available in subsequent commands
nix --version
```

#### CAVEAT

The Nix installer uses `sudo` so a password will still have to be entered manually. (This is not an issue for me, as I'm just trying to save time, and not fully automate the process - at least for now. There are workarounds though on how to [install Nix without root permissions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/222999/installing-nix-or-guix-without-root-permissions).)

#### Where are the Nix installer options documented?

They aren't documented. A [pull request is forthcoming](https://github.com/NixOS/nix/pull/7885), and [this NixOS Discourse thread](https://discourse.nixos.org/t/how-to-run-the-nix-installer-silently-from-a-shell-script/25633) lists all available options until then. (Also, here's a skeleton of a [man page draft for the installer](https://github.com/NixOS/nix/blob/fa816ecc1b36a34f08e3559a3003886a342c4718/doc/manual/src/command-ref/nix-install.md).)