# Software Install Permissions Only

Tags: linux, amazon-linux

We are looking at add users to groups that allow them to install software through yum on Amazon Linux 2 (RHEL), however am unsure how to grant a group access to only install software through it. Is this possible to do?

The reason we want to allow them access to install software is while yes, it allows them access to install things, there are other things we don't want users to be able to do, for example modifying software that was installed via root, or modifying files that only root should have access to to modify their experience 100% like security controls. But it will allow developers to install software they need without the need of a help desk installing everything for them.

Thank you.

Comment: I would look into sudo. It allows granting admin privileges to users for certain commands.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using `sudo` but remember that it is trivial to install absolutely **any** package, including a custom one which means users of this group can easily gain full access/root privileges. Check this question for `apt`: [Allow non-admin users to install packages via apt or rpm?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39572/allow-non-admin-users-to-install-packages-via-apt-or-rpm)